# Set a selection of cells to a certain color by clicking a button

Tags: excel, office-scripts, ms-office-script

I want to colorize selected fields from user with a Office Script.
Is that possible?

Robert

EDIT:

1. Select a number of cells, depending on which the user chooses
2. Press a Button (Make Cell Green)
3. Colorize the Cells which were selected.

Comment: Can you provide more detail on what you're trying to do? Are you trying to set certain cells to a specific color? If so, to which ones? And under what circumstances should those colors be set?

Comment: I would recommend starting `Action Recorder` on the Automate tab and doing the actions on a test workbook, then edit the recorded script to try doing what you want.

Comment: @BrianGonzalez  Step by Step
1. Select a number of cells, depending on which the user chooses
2. Press a Button (Make Cell Green)
3. Colorize the Cells which were selected.

Comment: @JayRathi-Microsoft 
I tried this but there is no possibility to change from a absolute selection A1:A5 to a dynamic one A1:AX (depending on the selection from user)

Answer (score 1):

You can use workbook.getSelectedRange() to get the user selected range in the workbook.

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    workbook.getSelectedRange().getFormat().getFill().setColor("4472C4");

}
```